# Git в phpstorm 2017 не работает

Tags: git, phpstorm

[image: Ошибка[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cSJG.png)

На первом скрине показан ответ phpstorm 2017 на втором более старой версии шторма, один и тот же путь, но разный ответ, не могу понять в чем причина?

Comment: ссылка на второй скрин под первым

Comment: Я вижу на первом скрине PhpStrom который запускается со среды Ubuntu, второй через Wine, и соответственно причина думаю тоже в том что разные окружения